# Calling javascript function from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, javascript-framework

I am using AJAxsolr framework for building my search UI. 
I have an index file which is an html file. This file has all the necessary script imports that import the javascript files. I have a javascript file script1.js which has a function as follows:

```
  function myfunction(){
     //Do the necessary stuff
  }
```

I have another js file mywidget.js which is my custom widget. It has the following function:

```
  (function ($) {
     AjaxSolr.MyWidget = AjaxSolr.AbstractTextWidget.extend({
        init: function(){

        }
        // and other functions

     }
  });
```

I want to call the function myfunction() in script1.js from the mywidget.js file. I tried the $.getScript() function but couldn't get to call the function. 
Can someone help me on this please?

Thank you!

Comment: make sure `myfunction` is defined above where you are calling it, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `script1.js` file before the `mywidget.js` file (ie. place one before the other in the HTML).

From there you should be able to call `myFunction` with no problems.

If after this you're still having issues, you can use `$.fn.myFunction()` to extend jQuery's prototype. In essence by doing this you'll be adding functionality to jQuery.